# Is onion and garlic foods toxic?

Tags: dogs, diet

Is it true that  onion and garlic food items are toxic to pet dogs and is dog foods like pedigree etc really good for pet dogs health?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes onion and garlic are toxic to most animals, it can cause hemolysis of the red blood cells.

Pedigree is one of the lower quality foods out there but some dogs do perfectly fine on it. If grocery store food like pedigree is the type of food in your price range I would grab Iams puppy/adult/senior depending on the lifestage of your dog.